# Do native speakers use the collocation of “ in result of” or "in the result of"?

Tags: collocations

When I am looking some academic papers, there are some sentences like:

"In result of the Fukushima accident, a large-scale diffusion of radioactivity took place. "

"In the result of these operations, X n points are shrunk (become smaller) to the center point X c. "

I am not sure whether they are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to use that construction is

**As a result of the Fukushima accident, a large scale diffusion of radioactivity took place.**

Alternatively

**The Fukushima accident resulted in a large scale diffusion of radioactivity.**

Or you could be less wordy with

**The Fukushima accident released a large amount of radioactivity.**

Comment: Thank a lot. So the second sentence also could modify into"As a result of these operations,...", is it right?

Comment: Absolutely. "As a result of ___" is a standard phrase.